# How to add shape file at EGIS in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, path, shapefile

I am using EGIS library and SfMap tool belongs to EGIS, but I cannot open or read shape file.
The name of the file that I try to open is `roads.shp`.
In `AddShapeFile` it says I should write:`(string path,string name,string labelFieldName)`. I write as in below but it gives an error such as"ArgumentException was unhandled". What should I do?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    sfMap1.AddShapeFile(@"C:\Users\Quanthema\Desktop\Paylasim\Performance Test", "roads", "");
}
```

Comment: `path` should include the file name, I think the second parameter `name` is anything you want. E.g. `sfMap1.AddShapeFile(@"C:\Users\Quanthema\Desktop\Paylasim\Performance Test\roads.shp", "My Roads", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API documentation](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/api/output/html/M_EGIS_Controls_SFMap_AddShapeFile_3_45ca51f2.htm) for `SFMap.AddShapeFile` says this about the parameters:

> path Type: System..String The file path to the ShapeFile
>    name Type: System..String The "display" name of the ShapeFile.
>   labelFieldName Type: System..String The name of the field in the ShapeFiles's DBF
>   file to use when rendering the shape labels

Where you have:

```
sfMap1.AddShapeFile(@"C:\Users\Quanthema\Desktop\Paylasim\Performance Test", "roads", "");
```

It looks like you are not providing the full file path for the first `path` parameter, and you have the file name in the "display" `name` field.

Try something like this:

```
sfMap1.AddShapeFile(@"C:\Users\Quanthema\Desktop\Paylasim\Performance Test\roads.shp", "ShapeFile", "");
```

From the example usage [here](http://www.easygisdotnet.com/api/Example1.aspx) it looks like you can pass in an empty string as the third parameter, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks you so much.